# complex looping in swig template

Tags: node.js, web, frontend, swig-template

Hi I have a array of questions as

```
[ { question: 'What is your Name', 
    relatedApi: '/put/user' },
  { question: 'What is your restaurant Name',
    relatedApi: '/put/user' },
  { question: 'Add a diss to your restaurant',
    relatedApi: '/post/item' } ]
```

I am designing everything in swig template , Now I want to design three forms which will pop up one after the other, each one is having input field and one question as per array content and will send a POST request on the relatedAPI ,and once the succes mesage is recived from the api next form with question will pops up. Have no idea how to make this possible in swig template , any help or suggestion is appreciable

Answer (score 0):

[Swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/) only compiles and render templates.
You need to write your GET and/or POST requests and then check for return status 200 depending on the API you're using.

In node.js, you have multiple starting points. Here is a couple:

- [requests](https://github.com/request/request)
- [needle](https://github.com/tomas/needle)
- native http module from node.js

Comment: got your point and somewhere figure this out as well , but if node do not close connection with browser is there a way to just notify browser for success full submission of form data and then asking for question 2 without reloading page ..!

Comment: You can handle your response from the API however you may like.